# Is there a way to convert string to double arrays as easy in c#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to convert string  to double arrays as easy  in c#?

from string:        "x -22.4, y 77.4 , z + 99.8"
to double array:    [-22.4, 77.4, 99.8]

or

from string:        "x -22.4  y 77.4   z + 99.8"
to double array:    [-22.4, 77.4, 99.8]

Comment: In the first example you have a comma before `z` whereas in the second you don't. Is this normal? Also is there a space between the `+` sign and the last number?

Answer (score 4):

This should work for both versions.

Remove the `+ with space` and the `,` from the string, split it at space chars, take the first, the third and the fifth element and convert them to double:

```
double[] doubleArray = 
     "x -22.4 y 77.4 z + 99.8"
          .Replace(",", "")
          .Replace("+", "")
          .Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Where((val, idx) => idx % 2 == 1)
          .Select(val => double.Parse(val))
          .ToArray()
```

Comment: thanks. the problem is that i need and in the same time  for the both strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split() method to split on commas and spaces. Then use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx)() to convert to double.